# pyqgis change or update attribute data with real-time data or Timer update，Memory has been growing

Tags: python, shapefile, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I update my shapefile attribute data by QTimer ,and labling it,
keep the lable visiable,change attribute by 1 minute,
but the Memory has been growing

***1***

```
    layers =self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    selectedLayerIndex=self.dlg.labelfield_2.currentIndex()
    sl=layers[selectedLayerIndex]
    CurrentSecond=QTime.currentTime().second()
    self.ldp = sl.dataProvider()
    features = self.ldp.getFeatures()
    fdindex=self.ldp.fieldNameIndex(self.dlg.labelfield.currentText())

    fdindex=self.ldp.fieldNameIndex(self.dlg.labelfield.currentText())
    for feature in features:
        self.UPDATEMAP[feature.id()] = { fdindex: str(CurrentSecond) }
    self.ldp.changeAttributeValues( self.UPDATEMAP )
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

***2***

```
    layers =self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    selectedLayerIndex=self.dlg.labelfield_2.currentIndex()
    sl=layers[selectedLayerIndex]
    CurrentSecond=QTime.currentTime().minute()
    self.ldp = sl.dataProvider()
    features = self.ldp.getFeatures()
    fdindex=self.ldp.fieldNameIndex(self.dlg.labelfield.currentText())
    sl.startEditing()
    for feature in features:
        feature[fdindex]=str(CurrentSecond)
        sl.updateFeature(feature)
    sl.commitChanges()
    self.iface.actionSaveEdits()
    if iface.mapCanvas().isCachingEnabled():
        sl.setCacheImage(None)
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

boththis two methods  have the metmory growth,so what can I do?